# Assign the same number to equal rows of a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Consider a column vector `A` in Matlab containing possibly repeated integers.

Using `unique`, I construct the vector `B` containing the elements of `A` without repetition.

Suppose I have a vector `C` of size `size(B,1)x1`.

I would like your help to construct a vector `D` of size `size(A,1)x1` assigning the same element of `C` to equal elements of `A`.

Let me explain better with an example.

```
clear
A=[2;
   3;
   3;
   1;
   4;
   2;
   2;
   4;
   5;
   1];

B=unique(A,'stable'); 
%B=[2;
%   3;
%   1;
%   4;
%   5] %selected elements

C=[100;
   101;
   102;
   103;
   104]; %size(B,1)x1
```

Then, starting allocating the top elements of `C` to the top elements of  `A`, I want to get

```
D=[100; %C(1)
   101; %C(2)
   101; %C(2)
   102; %C(3)
   103; %C(4)
   100; %C(1)
   100; %C(1)
   103; %C(4)
   104; %C(5)
   102];%C(3)
```

I have tried to use the indices released by `unique` but I could'n manage to get the desired output. Any help?

Comment: We shouldn't order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the second output of  [`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
[~, idx] = ismember(A,B)
D = C(idx);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array function to look up the index into A of each element of B:

```
idxs = arrayfun(@(x)find(B==x,1),A);
D=C(idxs)

D =

100
101
101
102
103
100
100
103
104
102
```